# Помогите отредактировать код JS чтобы в место редиректа выводилось сообщение

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код который делает редирект если блокируется реклама. Помогите сделать так чтобы в место редиректа, показывалось модальное окно к которому можно было добавлять стили css.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function() {
    if (jQuery('#solnisko111').height() == 0) { 
        window.location = 'https://forum.helpsetup.ru/viewtopic.php?f=94&t=428&p=963#p963'; 
    } 
}, 25000);
</script>
<div id="solnisko111"><script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> 
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-8611103670522457"
     data-ad-slot="9610912932"></ins> 
  <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>`
```

Comment: Прошу прощения я не дописал вопрос. В место редиректа чтоб модальное окно выводилось и можно было стили к нему подключать.

Answer (score 2):

Какое именно сообщение? В модалке, в блоке страницы, алерт? В 4 строке замени

```
window.location = 'https://forum.helpsetup.ru/viewtopic.php?f=94&t=428&p=963#p963;
```

На

`alert('реклама заблокирована')`;

Comment: В модалке надо сообщение выводить. А если стили css добавить для модального окна надо ? как указывать ? Какой брать типо div для стилей ? alert и для него писать стили ?